# How can I delete all of the nodes and relationships from the Memgraph database?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I want to delete all of the nodes and relationships from the Memgraph database. I know that could create a whole instance, but I don't want to do that.

Which Cypher query can I use to delete the content of the Memgraph database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all nodes and relationships from your Memgraph database use the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n;
```